# getting paragraph value in jquery

Tags: jquery

how to get the value of this paragraph in jquery

```
 <p class="editableText" id="$bid">$content</p>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p.editableText').each(function(){
      var content = $(this).val();
   });
});
```

is this a correct approach ?!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$('.editableText').html()` if it contains inner html or `$('.editableText').text()` for plain text

`.val()` should be used for inputs with a `value` attribute.

Comment: Good answer, really great. :)